# Changing Route Template in MVC 4 to be nameofvendor/controller/id

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm setting up a website that will have multiple vendors using one site. A url will look something like this

www.domainname.com/vendorname

But in MVC, after the slash by default goes to the controller. I know you can change routing tables, but I  need it to ignore everything after that first slash and still use the controller. It's just that the url would be www.domainname.com/vendorname/{controller}/{id}

How can I tweak this to ignore the first parameter and look to the 2nd and 3rd for the controller/id?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think  you're looking to adjust your `~/App_Start/RouteConfig.cs`:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default_Vendor",
  "{vendorname}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

From there, you can examine the `RouteData` for the `vendorname` and use it appropriately (maybe resolve a specific database or use it as a key in a table).